# What is the recommended way to include small CSS customizations to an extension?

Tags: extensions, css

I've installed an extension and want to make some CSS customizations to the modal pop-up that it provides. There are basic options in the backend for styles, but I want to use CSS to write some custom changes.

I come from a background in WordPress, so there I'd just enqueue a CSS file in my theme directory and maybe store it in some sort of "integrations" folder in my theme so I can organize it and know that the file pertains to a specific plugin.

What would be a similar way to do this in Magento?

Comment: What's the URL of the page? Is it for the front or backend?

Comment: No specific URL. It'd be on the front-end. I just want to write some CSS that will override some extension CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which page does your extension applied to.

In Magento, there are multiple ways to add CSS. I think for easier understanding, you can add CSS this way: this will add to all frontend pages

To add CSS to all pages, create this in your theme:

Create a file `app/design/frontend/Theme/Your_Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` if it doesn't exist.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Magento_Theme::your-css.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

And clear your cache. If needed you may have to deploy the static content.

Deploy content command from your SSH: `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

**UPDATE**

If you just want to override the CSS for any module then create a field called `_module.less`

`app/design/frontend/Theme/Your_Theme/Custom_Module/web/css/source/_module.less`

Then you will have to write `.less` CSS and it will override the styles.

Answer (score 0):

I quote from Magento official document

> For example, to override the Magento_Review module’s style, the directory path should be <your_theme_dir>/Magento_Review/web/css/source/_module.less.

For more information, check this link
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html#override-module-styles